# When I booted up my computer a message on the screen said my battery is irreversibly dead. Should I remove the dead battery?

Tags: battery, dell-inspiron

When I booted up my computer a message on the screen said my battery is irreversibly dead.

Must the dead battery be removed from my Dell Inspiron 15, 5000 series laptop to run safely?

Comment: Yes! Remove it. All the battery can do now is swell up at best or literally explode at worst.

Answer (score 6):

The battery should be replaced.

Old dead batteries can (and do) swell up so as to create a bigger problem.

Most modern laptops will not run (at least natively) without a battery and it is not recommended anyway.

Replace the battery.

**Footnote**: I do not know what caused your battery to go completely and irreversibly dead, but do use Battery Threshold to ensure the battery does not charge more than 80% if left connected to AC all the time. 80% is the generally accepted level of charge when constantly connected to AC.

Comment: Just removing it, without replacing, should be fine as well. Well, it'll turn off when you unplug AC, but that's how desktop PCs worked for decades, and they are still in use.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Having no battery sometime prevents updates being installed as the OS will not update without a battery to prevent issues if there is a power cut midway through the update.

Comment: @DavidPostill How does it install these updates on a desktop computer?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Actually, a lot of modern day laptops *won't* run without a battery. It seems to be a based on whether the battery is built-in or removable; if it's removable, then usually it will run without a battery (though there are exceptions), but if it's built-in, it almost always won't even turn on without the battery connected.

Comment: @Michael The OS can tell if it's on a laptop or desktop. So, while I haven't ever seen that behavior myself, it's definitely plausible.

Comment: Dell batteries are notorious for swelling, even when lightly used and taken care of properly. Unfortunately with this manufacturer it's just a part of owning the device. Early symptoms other than battery life dropping include laptop rocking on the desk due to bulging and touchpads popping out. They can sometimes be convinced to fix this under warranty.

Answer (score 0):

When my removable battery died on my Dell XPS 1645 I simply removed it: I never run it without AC anyway. No issues for the past several years with no battery installed.